# How many concurrent connection RDS handle?

Tags: mysql, performance-testing, load-testing, amazon-rds, database-tuning

I host my two MySql databases on Amazon RDS, which is db.m3.medium and db.r3.large having 5.6.27 innodb engine. Now I want to know, how many concurrent connections these instances can handle? How to load test it? What will be the impact if 1000 concurrent users access the databases?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors like MySQL servers configuration, data volumes, nature of requests, etc. The only way to tell it for sure is simulating your 1000 users with a load testing tool.

Few examples:

- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) -> [MySQL](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#mysql)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) -> [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) -> [Grinding a database with JDBC](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-gallery.html#jdbc.py)

If you will be happy with the databases performance with 1000 users you can gradually increase the load to identify the breaking point